# Deserializing a SOAP message from the file system

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I previously connected to a WCF endpoint, defined via a WSDL file. Everything was wonderful, and I retrieved data via;

```
var client = new ElementRetrieval_RPCClient();
var header = new header();
var elements = client.getAllElements(ref header, new getAllElementsRequest()).meList;

// Loop over elements.
```

However, because of ridiculous policies, my application must now parse the SOAP responses from a file (and rely on a 3rd party making the SOAP request for me, and dumping the response to the file for me to collect).

**I've tried;**

```
var converter = TypedMessageConverter.Create(typeof(getAllElementsResponse), "getAllElementsResponse", "", new XmlSerializerFormatAttribute());
var reader = XmlTextReader.Create(file);
var message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "getAllElementsResponse", reader);
var obj = (getAllElementsResponse) converter.FromMessage(message);
```

**... but this leaves the properties of `obj` to be `null` (although no errors are raised/ logged). I've also tried:**

```
var reader = XmlTextReader.Create(file);
var message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "getAllElementsResponse", reader);
var obj = message.GetBody<getAllElementsResponse>();
```

**... but this fails with a `SerializationException`:**

> Additional information: Expecting element 'getAllElementsResponse' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ElementRetrieval'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'getAllElementsResponse', namespace 'http://www.example.org/mri/xsd/mer/v1'.

**... here, the "Encountered" namespace is correct; but I don't know how to tell `GetBody<T>()` to *expect* that namespace?**

The `getAllElementsResponse` class (generated automatically by WCF) looks like the following (in case the attributes are important):

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class getAllElementsResponse {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://www.example.org/fmw/xsd/hdr/v1")]
    public ElementRetrieval.header header;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="getAllElementsResponse", Namespace="http://www.example.org/mri/xsd/mer/v1", Order=0)]
    public ElementRetrieval.MultipleMeObjectsResponseType getAllElementsResponse1;

    public getAllElementsResponse() {
    }

    public getAllElementsResponse(ElementRetrieval.header header, ElementRetrieval.MultipleMeObjectsResponseType getAllElementsResponse1) {
        this.header = header;
        this.getAllElementsResponse1 = getAllElementsResponse1;
    }
}
```

... and the `getAllElements` method has the following attributes:

```
// CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation getAllElements is neither RPC nor document wrapped.
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="getAllElements", ReplyAction="*")]
[System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(ElementRetrieval.getAllElementsException), Action="getAllElements", Name="getAllElementsException", Namespace="http://www.example.com/mri/xsd/mer/v1")]
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(xxx))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(xxx))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(xxx))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(xxx))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(xxx))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(xxx))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(xxx))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(xxx))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(xxx))]
```

Can anyone spot why either of these approaches are not working, and suggest a fix/ work around?

Answer (score 1):

The **GetBody<>** operation uses internally **DataContractSerializer** and therefore you have to add the **DataContract** attribute with specific namespace.

Because if you don't add it, the default one is used (By default CLR namespace is mapped to *http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Clr.Namespace* and this is the reason why are you getting the exception.

> Additional information: Expecting element 'getAllElementsResponse'
>   from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ElementRetrieval'..
>   Encountered 'Element' with name 'getAllElementsResponse', namespace
>   'http://www.example.org/mri/xsd/mer/v1'.

Try something like that:

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.example.org/fmw/xsd/hdr/v1")
public partial class getAllElementsResponse 
{
    [DataMember]
    [MessageHeader(Namespace="http://www.example.org/fmw/xsd/hdr/v1")]
    public ElementRetrieval.header header;

    [DataMember]
    [MessageBodyMember(Name="getAllElementsResponse", Namespace="http://www.example.org/mri/xsd/mer/v1", Order=0)]
    public ElementRetrieval.MultipleMeObjectsResponseType getAllElementsResponse1;
}
```

Hope it helps